# How do I ignore certain file types with cppcheck?

Tags: c++, qt-creator, cppcheck

Im using cppcheck to analyze my c++ code. I have some .svg/.png files in my source, which makes cppcheck report a lot of errors of the following type:

> fileName1.svg:2: error: Cppcheck: Invalid number of character (() when these macros are defined: ''.

Is there an easy way I can make cppcheck ignore files of a certain type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally cppcheck checks only C and C++ files.

However, if you tell cppcheck to check `.svg` files it will check those. For example:

```
cppcheck filename1.svg
```

or

```
cppcheck *.*
```

So check your command line and make sure you are not giving cppcheck `.svg` filenames.

If you have problems, let me see your command line.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I dont run cppcheck from command line, but I use the QtcCppcheck plugin for Qt Creator. It seems like this runs the command on all files in the project. 
There is an option to put in additional arguments for cppcheck.

So I guess my question is if there are an option to put in a ignore filter or something simluar as arguments when running cppcheck?

Comment: ok. no there is not such option. there are options for stopping diagnostics that you probably could use but that is not ideal here. the QtcCppcheck plugin should not include all project files.